# Android replace strings doesnt work

Tags: java, android

in this below String arrays i have this tags:

```
String[] tags = {
        "<mft:A>",
        "<mft:S>",
        "<mft:R>",
        "</mft:A>",
        "</mft:S>",
        "</mft:R>"
};
```

and i want to replace them with this `html` tags:

```
String[] replacementHtmlTags = {
        "<font color=\"red\">",
        "<font color=\"green\">",
        "<font color=\"blue\">",
        "</font>",
        "</font>",
        "</font>"
};
```

now after define targets and replacements my code doesn't work:

```
String rawParagraph = "11111 <mft:A>22222</mft:A> 33333 <mft:S> 44444 <mft:A> 555555 <mft:S> 66666 </mft:S></mft:A></mft:S><mft:R> 77777 </mft:R>"

for (int tag = 0; tag < tags.length; tag++) {
    rawParagraph.replace(tags[tag], replacementHtmlTags[tag]);
}
```

Comment: Strings are *immutable*, so `replace()` returns the new value. It doesn't (can't) update the current value.

Comment: @Andreas ok, so how can i replace all tags using with array like with my code?

Comment: @Andreas, thanks, problem resolved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should follow this approach for better usability and mapping:

```
public static HashMap<String, String> keyVal;

static {
    keyVal = new HashMap<String, String>();
    keyVal.put("<mft:A>", "<font color=\\red\">");
    keyVal.put("<mft:S>", "<font color=\\green\">");
    keyVal.put("<mft:R>", "<font color=\\blue\">");
    keyVal.put("</mft:A>", "</font>");
    keyVal.put("</mft:S>", "</font>");
    keyVal.put("</mft:R>", "</font>");
}

public String replaceTag(String replace) {
    for(String key:keyVal.keySet())
        replace=replace.replaceAll(key,keyVal.get(key));
    return replace;
}
```